# Firebase Realtime Database rules for "secret" url sharing

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm playing around with a simple web app that uses JS to interact with a Firebase Realtime Database that looks something like this:

```
{
  "some-collection": {
    "some-obscure-long-uuid": {
      "name": {
        "info_1": "foo",
        "info_2": "bar"
      }
    },
    "some-other-obscure-long-uuid": {
      "name": {
        "info_1": "foo",
        "info_2": "bar"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The idea is not to use any form of authentication but to allow users to get a random shareable link, say `www.myapp.com/some-obscure-long-uuid/index.html`, so that other people can see and perform changes in real-time. With this in mind, I'm trying to find a set of rules that:

- Don't expose the children of `"some-collection"` publicly
- Give read and write access to the `"some-obscure-long-uuid"` child to anyone with the secret URL `www.myapp.com/some-obscure-long-uuid/index.html`

I've read the docs and suspect this can be achieved using the `newData` variable, but cannot get my head round to how to use it. Hope this makes sense and thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if I understood correctly but below should give read-write access to anyone who is attempting to read or write to path `some-collection/[some-obscure-long-uuid]` and your `some-collection` parent would be safe from getting queried without anyone specifying the full path.

```
{
 "rules": {
    "some-collection": {
       ".read": "false",
       ".write": "false",
       "$some-obscure-long-uuid": {
         ".read": "true",
         ".write": "true",
       }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: this is exactly what I was after, sorry the question may have been a bit unclear!